# Can anyone help me to get frontend translations only? Magento2

Tags: magento2, translate, multi-language, mageplaza

My site having two different languages, English and French. I have used MagePlaza's French language pack for the French translations. The translation CSV file contains more than 14k rows! So, it is really hard for me to check if the translation is correct or not. I want only frontend translations and reduce these rows as low as possible. Any help?

Comment: Is there any problem with the language package? Why did you want to reduce the size?

Comment: @JeevaChezhiyan, Thanks for the reply. My client wanted to see/edit translations. So it would take a long time. If I can reduce the file to 2000-3000 rows by filtering only frontend and necessary translations, It would be helpful for him.

Comment: @user79969 did u find any solution for this? I'm also facing same issue

Answer (score 2):

**For the back-end to be in English** use the below configuration

> system > config > (general) general > locale options > locale >
>   English (US)

while doing it check that

- You are on the page that need to be in English itself (**default config**) or that french website whatever page you are in, which will be on the top left.

**For front-end to be in French**

You can you those Mageplaza extensions but as you said to reduce content in csv, we couldn't do that.

If we try to reduce those content on those , then your front end page will be affected, like you may get a half translated French page.

You may you the **Google translate tool kit** , not the **google translate** as you upload the file and translate for you to ensure the translation.

Comment: @user79969 For you to upload the csv file for language conversion for google translate tool kit is https://translate.google.com/toolkit/list#translations/active.

Comment: That is not really the question. The goal is to be able to retrieve only the translation keys used in frontend. (indeed frontend translation key can also be used in admin, but it is not an issue). The goal is to be able to translate in all language only the frontend and keep english value for backend. The magento default tool do not provide this feature.

Answer (score -1):

Use inline Translation feature on Magento 2.[Reference Link](https://docs.magento.com/m2/ee/user_guide/system/translate-inline.html)

On magento by default no way to get the translation strings based on frontend / backend. So you have only option to use inline translation and ask your client to translate.

Answer (score -1):

Please check this link, it will work on frontend only,
https://www.mageplaza.com/magento-2-translation/

In Magento, there is different ways to create translation for frontend and backend,

After following this link, create you languagpack.csv file in your theme.

**EXAMPLE:**

```
app/design/frontend/yourtheme/name/i18n/en_US.csv
```

and translate data here.

Hope it helps!